# Python(AI Constraint satisfaction problem) Fitting square and/or rectangular (2d) tiles onto a rectangular ground

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, artificial-intelligence

I have to arrange and/or fit 2d tiles into a 2d square or rectangular plane with AI algorithm using python program. Each tile has a length and width. For example if a plane is 4x3 and set of tiles is

S={(2,3),(1,2),(2,2)}

these tiles can be rotated 90 degrees in order to fit the matrix.

input
first line contains length and width of the plane
second line number of tiles
and then the length,width of the subsequent tiles

but the inputs should be tab seperated

for eg

```
4    3
3
2    3
1    2
2    2
```

output
for eg

```
1    1    2   2
1    1    3   3
1    1    3   3
```

I have trouble solving this as i have to use only standard libraries in python no NumPy and no CSP library

~Edit 2`
my code so far I cant figure out how to add algorithm without csp library or to generate grid

```py
from sys import stdin
a = stdin.readline()

x = a.split()

rectangular_plane = [[0] * int(x[0]) for i in range(int(x[1]))]
num_of_rectangles = stdin.readline()

r_widths = []
r_lengths= []

for l in range(int(num_of_rectangles)):
    b = stdin.readline()
    y = b.split()

r_lengths.insert(l,y[0])
r_widths.insert(l,y[1])
```

Comment: If you do not have a CSP / SAT library, implement a systematic search algorithm (guess + backtracking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved task with [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) approach and without any non-standard modules.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVM9b8IwEN39K64TdklRAp2Q6NixS7tZHlJxNIbgWLFpVP48PcdAiEjUqRkS5969u3cftj@@qMzidNJ7W9Ue3I9jzBz2DlZQauf5PrdcG58EZOb8WptZjfmai5mzpfZcCMFsk4AtiBGIMl3OFfPXAEdteWtfLAlIos9zOBMzdw4pa4mGeydgdQ5BAZjegDvsuUSZKngElJmCTVUDgjbgnRLwsALbEGSLJQN6bE1C@eSt8mAr5/RniQ8TwbB0GB3WuIH3qvxG/piA9qQwJeH0easMiugTHkptQbvW3FnbFOQsoyBKHeToIKfOzRdyWwh1G4MyvKwutfXjtIWkgWr7wBXMAojpPdpVilkCaNYkaQJU57BT316jP9QGPuoDstt0niboi5BSklipvaIiyRSPmRIJ8OvP1Z4qofoCj01oUNsf3/SQqkWoJVPIBuC7VsJTEETOYrhB2xvnJjg3I87nYeRlya3cKbmFJZGnRFBh345xjLsunKbdCHghRqJdJAxyxintTO4UUGNGGfqyru2uxt7FhbV/5Bma8/@VcOxKOCd@zenSMXYuwtCNjIXcxB65rafTMyzYgs3pncGcvnP2Cw)

```
import sys

nums = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))
pw, ph = nums[0:2]
ts = list(zip(nums[3::2], nums[4::2]))
assert len(ts) == nums[2]

if sum([e[0] * e[1] for e in ts]) != pw * ph:
    print('Not possible!')
else:
    def Solve(*, it = 0, p = None):
        if p is None:
            p = [[0] * pw for i in range(ph)]
        if it >= len(ts):
            for e0 in p:
                for e1 in e0:
                    print(e1, end = ' ')
                print()
            return True
        for tw, th in [(ts[it][0], ts[it][1]), (ts[it][1], ts[it][0])]:
            zw = [0] * tw
            ow = [it + 1] * tw
            for i in range(ph - th + 1):
                for j in range(pw - tw + 1):
                    if all(p[k][j : j + tw] == zw for k in range(i, i + th)):
                        for k in range(i, i + th):
                            p[k][j : j + tw] = ow
                        if Solve(it = it + 1, p = p):
                            return True
                        for k in range(i, i + th):
                            p[k][j : j + tw] = zw
        return False

    if not Solve():
        print('Not possible!')
```

Example input:

```
4 3
3
2 3
1 2
2 2
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 2
1 1 3 3
1 1 3 3
```

Comment: def Solve(*, it = 0, p = [[0] * pw for i in range(ph)]): when i try to test this into pycharm python 3 IDE it gives error that variable i is not used and that default argument value is mutable

Comment: @abdulrehman It is just a warning of IDE, IDE always warns about possibly strange constructions that may lead to some errors. But here is a totally valid Python construction and I used it correctly. So IDE will warn but this python code should work everywhere. Do you say that python code stops with some exception or that IDE just prints a warning but still runs code? An example of that it runs correctly is link above code `Try it online!` there code runs correctly and prints result without errors.

Comment: @abdulrehman I've modified code a bit so that IDE should not warn any more! Try again!